# Uncorrelated mutation with one step size

Tags: genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm, genetic-programming, genetic

I'm reading the book Introduction to [Evolutionary Computing, A.E. Eiben, J.E. Smith (first edition)](https://www.springer.com/la/book/9783642072857), and in the section 4.4.1, Uncorrelated mutation with one step size, first paragraph said:

> "The sigma is mutated each time step by multiplying it by a term
>   tau..."

What does *"each time step"* mean?

I think it can means:

1. If I'm mutating and individual with 5 object variables, I have to mutate sigma one time, and mutate each object variable with that sigma mutated.
2. Or, in the same individual with 5 object variables, I have to mutate sigma, applied this sigma mutated to one object variable, mutate again sigma and applied to the second object variable, and continue doing the same for the rest of object variables.

Comment: When talking about time steps in evolutionary computation, it normally refers to generations.  I don't have this particular book, so I can't be sure what it's talking about.

Comment: To me only the first meaning makes sense but as Charles suggested we cannot be sure...

Answer (score 0):

"each time step" means each generation. You're going to mutated one time each generation.